# Neural Network MPC

Tags: python, optimization, gekko, mpc

So I want to use Neural Network as my learned dynamic model function for MPC control in Python.
I have not found any example/documention of doing this with open-source optimization packages like CASADI , GEKKO , do-mpc ? does any one have some reference/suggestion for achieving this?
THANKS

Edit 01
a) I have tried CASADI + tensorflow model
CASADI have a blog of how to use tensorflow model with CASADI. I am entirely not sure if I have done the implementation correctly  as obviously I am  not getting expected results.
b) Upon looking on Internet there is "mpc. Pytorch" library which is a mpc toolbox which provides nn models as well.
Not sure of its capability
C) do-mpc which is based on CASADI is planning to integrate NN model.
d) AS mentioned by @john gekko has the capability to use NN in mpc.

does any one know any other ways?

Comment: Please post anything you have tried prior, if anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with a Neural Network and MPC: [TCLab G - Nonlinear MPC](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabG). A potentially better way is to use an LSTM to emulate control (PID or MPC) as shown in a series of articles in [Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/emulating-a-pid-controller-with-long-short-term-memory-part-1-bb5b87165b08) or this [course exercise on emulating a PID or MPC](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/LSTMAutomation). This approach is also the basis for many explicit MPC publications that use methods for storage and retrieval of the solutions. I published an article on this method that includes a case study with ISAT and a Neural Network.

Hedengren, J. D. and Edgar, T. F., [Approximate Nonlinear Model Predictive Control with In Situ Adaptive Tabulation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098135407000531?via%3Dihub), Computers and Chemical Engineering, Volume 32, pp. 706-714, 2008. [Preprint](http://www.hedengren.net/research/Publications/CACE/hedengren_cace_2006.pdf)

Using a storage and retrieval approach, you don't need to solve the MPC application each cycle, only use the machine learned prediction that is trained based on prior MPC moves.

Comment: Here is a new link on using an LSTM to emulate the MPC. It works well on a MIMO (2x2) MPC (see Example 2): https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/LSTMNetwork